# How regex pattern write to check at least one string and number in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have an issue related to regex check at least one string and number which exclude any sign like @!#%^&*.
I have read many articles but I still can not find the correct answer as my expectation result.

Example: I have a string like : 111AB11111

My expectation result:
If input string

1. "1111"=>false
2. "AAA" =>false
3. "1A" => true
4. "A1" => true
5. "111AAA111"=>true
6. "AAA11111AA"=>true
7. "#AA111BBB"=>false
8. "111AAAA$"=>false

Which java regex patter can show above mentioned cases
Thank for your value time for checking and suggestion
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String#matches` with the following regex pattern:

```
^[A-Z0-9]*(?:[0-9][A-Z0-9]*[A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]*$
```

Sample Java code:

```java
List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "111AB", "111", "AB", "111AB$" });
for (String input : inputs) {
    if (input.matches("[A-Z0-9]*(?:[0-9][A-Z0-9]*[A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]*")) {
        System.out.println(input + " => VALID");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(input + " => INVALID");
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
111AB => VALID
111 => INVALID
AB => INVALID
111AB$ => INVALID
```

Note that the regex pattern actually used with `String#matches` do not have leading/trailing `^/$` anchors.  This is because the `matches` API implicitly applies the regex pattern to the entire string.

For an explanation of the regex pattern, it simply tries to match an input with has at least one digit or letter, in any order.

Comment: Biegenleisen Thank you brother for your answer, it works  but I want to exclude any  special character and sign like : \t\n &#$%@& how can I do that.

Comment: Edit your question and reveal the actual problem.  Note that `\t` is not typically considered a special character.

Comment: Thank @Tim Biegeleisen again for your answer, I just update my question please you help to check how can I exclude those sign. Which regex should be add on your provided above.

Comment: @James I have updated my answer per your latest requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This would accomplish your goal:

`^(?:[0-9]+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]*$`

Digits preceding alpha, or alphas preceding a digit, followed by only alphas and digits.